# Symfony2 and Doctrine: how to make an atomic operation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Imagine this scenario:

I have an array of ids for some entities that have to be deleted from database (i.e. a couple of externals keys that identifies a record into a third table) and an array of ids for some entities that have to be updated/inserted (based on some criteria that, in this moment, doesn't matters).

What can I do for delete those entities ?

- Load them from db (repository way)
- Call `delete()` on the obtained objects
- Call `flush()` onto my entity manager

In that scenario I can make all my operation atomical as I can update/insert other records before call `flush()`.

But why have I to load from db some records just for delete them? So I wrote my personal DQL query (into repo) and call it.
The problem is that if I call that function into my repo, this operation is done immediatly and so my "atomicity" can't be guaranteed.

So, how can I "jump" over this obstacle by following the second "delete-option" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `flush()` you're making Doctrine to start [transactions implicitly](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-1-implicitly). It is also possible to [use transactions explicitly](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-2-explicitly) and that approach should solve your problem.